# When downloading the image in ipad mini, it opens in encoded format

Tags: c#

I have the below code to download the file

```
byte[] byteInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(args.Path), args.Names[0]));
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.Combine(args.Path, args.Names[0]));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + args.Names[0]);
Response.BinaryWrite(byteInfo);
```

It works well on Windows and MAC devices. But on IPAD mini, it open the image in encoded format like below

```
IHDR         o³oa   sRGB ®Îé  ïiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp     <x:xm
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: What type of file is it? What is the value of `Response.ContentType`?

Comment: Download file is png type

Comment: Response.contentType was received as "image/png"

Comment: What happens if you comment out the 3rd and / or 5th lines?

Comment: By commenting the 5th line, 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + args.Names[0]);

Image displays in encoded format in windows OS also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this issue by adding 
Response.Flush()
Response.End()